# (Content-Lenght mismatch: Requested Header Indicated)Chrome having issue in upload large image files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, kendo-ui

I am using MVC and KENDO UI to upload a file - it works fine in all browsers except Chrome - it does not upload a large sized file.

It threw an error of 'Content-Length mismatch: Request header indicated.....'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try sending the upload without setting content-length explicitly.

Comment: How do you do that in javascript